# Trackpad gestures stop working in Safari on MacOS Yosemite

Tags: safari

I cannot tell what is the reason that the trackpad gestures stop working but here are the symptoms:

- Trackpad gestures would be working fine. For instance: smart zoom (double finger tap) or Swipe with two fingers to go to the previous page
- After a while, Safari stops reacting to those gestures. Even If I try to close and kill all Safari instances, I still get this problem. The solution is to reboot then those gestures work again.

Did anyone face this problem? How to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT 14_1204:** It's a Safari bug. Disabling extensions seemed to work, but **it started again**. It only seems to affect Safari and App Store, so it's probably related to the swipe animation handling in those apps.

**EDIT 14_1129:** After a few days, **the problem came back for me**. Resetting PRAM is apparantly working for other people, but in my case, <strike>I suspect it was **interference from a Safari Extension**. I haven't narrowed it down exactly, yet, but I only had four extensions which could've been the culprit.</strike>

1. No More iTunes
2. Instapaper
3. Reddit Enhancement Suite
4. Evernote Web Clipper

After disabling (but not uninstalling) all extensions and restarting my Mac, gestures seem to be back at 100% for a good while now. Still, I can't say for sure that extensions were the issue. The issue also cropped up with the Mac App Store before the fix, and I'm not sure what to take from that.

**Original Answer:**
<strike>Resetting PRAM worked for me</strike>. Apple's instructions page for resetting PRAM is unavailable at the moment, but plenty of sites have reposted them. From [ihash.eu](http://www.ihash.eu/2014/10/reset-macs-pram-os-x-10-10-yosemite/):

> 1. **Shut down** your Mac.
> 2. Locate the following keys on the keyboard: **Option, Command (⌘), P,
>      and R**. You will need to hold these keys down simultaneously in step
>      4.pram reset graphic How To Reset Macs PRAM in OS X 10.10 Yosemite
> 3. **Turn on** your Mac.
> 4. **Immediately press and hold the Option-Command-P-R keys**. You must
>      press this key combination before the gray screen appears.Continue
>      holding the keys down until your Mac restarts, and you hear the
>      startup sound for the second time.
> 5. **Release** the keys.
>
> **Words of Caution:**
>
> **If you have a Redundant Array of Independent Disks** (RAID) scheme set
>   up, your computer may not start up if you reset parameter
>   random-access memory (PRAM) when you restart.
>
> If this happens, hold down the Option key while you restart your
>   computer. Then select your startup disk when you see the prompt. After
>   you successfully start up your computer, choose Apple menu > System
>   Preferences, click Startup Disk, then select your startup disk.
>
> **Resetting PRAM may change some system settings and preferences.**
>   Remember that your chosen startup disk, time zone, and sound volume
>   are reset to their default values when you zap your PRAM. Use System
>   Preferences to restore your settings.

Comment: thank you. it seems the problem went away by itself. i am new to MacOS and feel hesitant to mess with PRAM.